# How to filter/resample array with classes by majority voting?

Tags: python, filter, resampling

Imagine I have an array or pandas Series with 4 classes, but the classes are varying a lot with each step. This is just an example (you can generate a more realistic one if you want):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(seed=0) # to generate always the same numbers
x = np.random.randint(4, size=(100))
```

As they vary a lot, I would like to upscale them (or filter or resample) by a majority voting technique or other method. Maybe looking around the 5 nearest samples and then that specific sample would have the most frequent class. And in the end I would have an array with a more 'packed' face.

This scheme should represent what I mean:

[image]

Anyone could help me?

Comment: What is preventing you from even *attempting* to write code for this yourself?

Comment: Knowledge. I just have the idea, but I simply do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't say this is pretty at all, but it seems to do the trick.

```
import numpy as np    

def majorityVoting(index, array, groupSize=5):
    groupSizeFloor = groupSize // 2
    arrayCount = len(array)

    if index <= groupSizeFloor:
        first = 0
        last = groupSize
    elif index >= arrayCount - (groupSize // 2):
        first = arrayCount - groupSize
        last = arrayCount
    else:
        first = index - groupSizeFloor
        last = index + groupSizeFloor + 1

    return np.bincount(array[first:last]).argmax()

np.random.seed(seed=0)
arr = np.random.randint(4, size=100)
majoritySorted = [majorityVoting(i, arr) for i in range(len(arr))]
```